# mod_rewrite a subdomain URL to another website

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I need to create a redirect so that the URL

`domain1.mysite.com/user/register`

goes to

`differentsite.com/user/register`

That's the only URL I need to redirect (the rest of domain1.mysite.com stays where it is). There is only one htaccess file for the whole site (www.mysite.com, domain1.mysite.com, domain2.mysite.com, etc), so I can't just redirect `/user/register` because `www.mysite.com/user/register` shouldn't be redirected.

(I could probably figure this out eventually but mod_rewrite rules and the flu don't mix.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something along the lines of:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^user/register$ http://differentsite.com/user/register [R=301,L]
```